# Binary Search, when should I increment high or low?

Tags: binary-search

I am having difficult to understand how to increment low or high.

For instance, this is a question from leetcode:

> Implement int sqrt(int x).

My code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int mySqrt(int x) {
        if (x<=0) return 0;
        int low=1, high=x, mid=0; 
        while (low<=high){          // should I do low<high?
            mid=low+(high-low)/2;
            if (x/mid==mid) return mid; 
            if (x/mid>mid) low= mid+1;  //can I just do low=mid?
            else           high=mid-1; // can I do high =mid?

        }
        return high;  //after breaking the loop, should I return high or low?

    }
};
```

You see, after a condition is fufill, I don't know whether I should set `low=mid` OR `low=mid+1`. Why `mid+1`?

In general, I am having trouble to see whether I should increment low from mid point or not. I am also having trouble when should I include `low <= high` or `low < high` in the `while` loop.

Comment: if (x/mid==mid) return mid;  here you check for mid as square root if it is then it is returned from here. so we tend to not check it again. So we do low= mid+1 and high = mid -1

Comment: And By this method you are not going to get square root of any number except few cases.

Comment: Read here. Hope this will clear all your doubts. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/square-root-of-a-perfect-square/

Answer (score 1):

Your algo is not binary search.
Also, it doesn't work.

Take example x = 5

```
Initial:
low = 1, high = 5

Iter 1:
mid = 3
5/3 = 1 so high = 4

Iter 2:
mid = 2.5 => 2 (because int)
5/2 = 2 (because int)

<returns 2>
```

For perfect square inputs, your algo will give correct results only through `mid` not `high` or `low`.

BTW you need to increase `mid` if `x/mid > mid` and you need to decrease it otherwise. Your method of increasing and decreasing `mid` is incrementing `low`, or decrementing `high` respectively.

This is OK, but this doesn't yield a binary search. Your `high` would be walking through all the integers from `x` to `(2*sqrt - 1)`.

Please follow @sinsuren comment to a far better solution

Answer (score 0):

This is [Babylonian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots) method for square root:

```
/*Returns the square root of n.*/
float squareRoot(float n)
{
  /*We are using n itself as initial approximation
   This can definitely be improved */
  float x = n;
  float y = 1;
  float e = 0.000001; /* e decides the accuracy level*/
  while(x - y > e)
  {
    x = (x + y)/2;
    y = n/x;
  }
  return x;
}
```

For more understanding you can always follow [this link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/square-root-of-a-perfect-square/)